# Libreoffice 6.0.1.1 Writer on Ubuntu 16.04 opens then closes. Why?

Tags: 16.04, lts

LibreOffice 6.0.1.1 recently installed on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
All packages will open except Writer which opens then closes.
Initially crash occurred and fault was sent.

Comment: can you tell us how you installed it please? I ask because earlier posts of advice talked of deleting; or purging; earlier installs of LibreOffice; one can add a ppa that manages this; but it is only at 5.4 where many will stay; till 6 is added to the ppa

Answer (score 0):

## PPA clearly states you will be on bleeding-edge

When you attempt to [add the PPA](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/02/install-libreoffice-6-0-on-ubuntu) you are warned:

> In general, this PPA is *not* for the average user to install without
> a closer look (if it would be, its packages would be in the main
> repositories). OTOH, it is *way* *better* to use packages from this
> PPA than using the *.deb files that The Document Foundation provides
> upstream, which are intentionally build against a very old baseline
> for maximum compatibility. So, *if* you want to be on the bleeding
> edge, do it here, not with upstream *.debs.

at this point you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and the PPA will not be added.

Answer (score 0):

If you have downloaded LibreOffice 6.0.1.1 from the official website or installed it from a PPA, try a better way of installing LibreOffice 6.0.1.1 by installing the LibreOffice snap package. To install it in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu  open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install libreoffice
```

Because the libreoffice snap package is a standalone package, it opens a little bit slower than the preinstalled version of LibreOffice, but it runs about the same.